# imac wi-fi problems

Tags: wifi, imac

I'm having a serious problem with WiFi on my iMac 21.5 inch running OS X Lion, up to date. It keeps disconnecting and when I reconnect it, it disconnects again, sometimes it stays on for about an hour or two, then disconnects again. Sometimes I have to restart my WiFi's modem. I check my phone, WiFi stays on all the time but only my iMac that keep disconnecting for no reason at all.

Is there any way to fix this? I've tried to Google and some answers I've already followed but none of them seem to work for me, so I thought I might try here see if any of you guys could help me with this problem. It's so annoying when I'm trying to search or even just watch YouTube videos and then it cuts off and on and off so many times. I'm using **eircom** broadband from Ireland.

Answer (score 2):

In a wireless network there are many causes of failure.  Is there a cordless phone in your house that uses the same frequency as wireless networks (2.4 GHz or 5 GHz)?  Is there another device that uses these frequencies?  Do you live in a noisy area (an apartment with people above, below you, left and right of you) where people are using devices they have?

Have you (can you) tried moving the computer closer to the wireless modem?  Is this more common during the day (when most people are at work), or at night (when most people are home)?  Do you have fluorescent lighting?  Are there any Amateur radio operators in the area that do microwave work?

What have you tried?  Have you seen any change with what you've tried?